# Any friendly creatures in Xen?

Tags: half-life

In the Half-life universe, are there any friendly creatures, except for the rescued Vortigaunts?

The Wikipedia articles about Xen show only unfriendly creatures.

Comment: [Boids](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Boid) don't appear to be actively hostile. Does that count?

Comment: [Protozoans](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Protozoan) don't appear to be actively hostile. Does that count?

Comment: Technically [Barnacles](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Barnacle) aren't hostile they just try to eat whatever comes to them. The [Protozoan](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Protozoan) also doesn't appear to be hostile though I'm not sure it counts as it has no AI.

Comment: @Valorum I think Boids do count, said to be inoffensive.

Comment: I always thought Protozoans aren't wildlife, sort of artificial creatures.

Comment: @SovereignSun - There you go. Self-answer away, my friend.